# Why was this answer deleted?

Tags: discussion

Can someone please explain why [this](https://health.stackexchange.com/a/1957/805) answer was deleted?

Answer (score 4):

Since I deleted it, it's up to me to explain.

The OP asks if it's possible that a mass he seems to have developed in so short a time after multiple imaging studies is cancer. Your answer:

> Yes, it is possible. Cancer is a living, growing thing and it's entirely possible that what was not detectable nine months ago will be detectable now. It's also possible the mass you feel is something other than cancer. I would urge you not to postpone your appointment with the urologist. Pain and a palpable mass are not normal.

Basically, the only thing you're saying here is, "Yes, anything is possible." You haven't cited any studies about how rapidly even an aggressive testicular cancer can grow from non-detectable on MRI to palpable, or if a dull ache is part of the picture in testicular cancer, or more likely that of the diagnosis he already has. The possibility that this is due to his hydrocele and varicocele are ignored. The OP scheduled a trip to the urologist. You told him not to postpone it. I don't see that there any indication he was going to.

So, at best it's a comment, and since answers in comments aren't allowed, it was deleted.

It gets tedious repeatedly telling users who are completely capable of understanding this site's policies that this isn't a discussion forum. It's a health site with standards similar to Skeptics.

There is no reason why such a poor answer should stay. It doesn't address the OP's real question except in a very superficial manner.

Comment: I don't think much more of an answer is possible given the lack of information he provided and the actual question he asked. He didn't ask for a treatise on testicular cancer. His question was quite focused, actually, and a definitive answer wouldn't be possible. In fact, I wouldn't have been surprised if the question had been closed. Be that as it may, I'm sorry I've contributed to the tedium of the job you chose. I'll be sure to curb that.

Comment: However, I do find the practice of deleting reasonable, well-intentioned answers without notice rather distasteful. I haven't encountered that in any other SE forum.

Comment: "...on any other forum" is an argument that is irrelevant. This is a particular site with particular expectations. Skeptics is similar. A differential is what the OP was asking for, not a treatise on testicular cancer. Your arguments as presented are not compelling. "[R]easonable, well-intentioned answers" are often so only in the eye of the one giving said answer. That's not good enough for Health.SE. Otherwise all the answers would be acceptable.

Comment: "[W]ithout notice..." There is no requirement to give such notice. If you want to edit your answer to make it better (including sources), I would be happy to undelete it temporarily to give you an opportunity to do so.

Comment: As you said, other sites are irrelevant here so what skeptics does is irrelevant. You're substituting your opinion of what constitutes a good answer for community voting. And yet instead of downvoting and leaving a comment indicating why you dislike it, you used your mod powers to summarily delete it, the same as you would do if it were spam or an abusive post. I don't think that's how SE is intended to work. It's disrespectful, dismissive, and a wee bit tyrannical. Do I resent being treated the same as spammers? Yes sir, I do. Leave the answer deleted.

Comment: I am not substituting my opinion for community voting. I am enforcing site policy, which is different altogether and which has been discussed in meta and voted on. If you just can't understand why Health.SE has higher standards than most SE sites after everything discussed in meta, I really hate to say it (because I think you have given helpful answers), but perhaps this isn't the site for you.

Comment: It's not about the standards.

Comment: Then perhaps you can edit your question and expand in order to clarify what it *is* about?